# Perform a function OnRender in React Native

Tags: function, react-native, render

The following is the code that generates a series of buttons. As the initial render takes place a function determines whether the element has a prop called init. If it does that it performs the action as if that button had been clicked.

Technically this code works but it triggers a warning as it is effective triggering a re-render in the middle of a render. How do you trigger an effective OnRender functions?

```
export class NavTabItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        global.register(this, 'screen')
    }

    NavTabAction = () => {
        global.setState({
            screen: this.props.screen,
        })
    }

    render() {

// determine whether the element has the prop of init and if it does click on it.

        if(this.props.init){
            this.NavTabAction()
        }

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.NavTabAction}>
                <View style={global.state.screen == this.props.screen ? [styles.NavTabItem, styles.NavTabItemSelected] : styles.NavTabItem}>
                    <View style={styles.NavTabIcon} />
                    <TextCap11 style={styles.NavTabLabel}>{this.props.children}</TextCap11>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is caused by performing a function on a component that is still rendering and though it technically worked, the solution is in line with the question.

There are a number of built in functions including one that would meet the requirements of an effective onRender.

Remove the script from the render and place it above render inside componentDidMount() function.

```
componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.init){
            this.NavTabAction()
        }
    }
```

QED

Answer (score 3):

For class-based React components, such as in your example, you would use the [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle method, which is fired only once after the component has loaded, e.g.:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.NavTabAction();
}
```

That said, I would encourage you to use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), as the React world is moving away from class-based components to functional components + hooks.

To achieve similar componentDidMount functionality with hooks, you would use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) like this in a *functional* component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  this.NavTabAction();
}, []);  // the [] is important here to behave similar to componentDidMount.
```

Comment: Looks worth understanding about this further. Copying your useEffect directly caused an error. Do I take it there is a bit more to learn about this before just using it?

Comment: Right you would need to refactor your component as a functional component. The first example in the [effect hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) doc is a good one to start with (and don't forget to export the function if you will need to import it elsewhere). I'd highly recommend reading through the [React Hooks docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) however, for a good foundation. Good luck!